# What is the meaning of the S flag in PSFzf's output?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, fzf, psfzf

I am using [PSFzf](https://github.com/kelleyma49/PSFzf) which integrates `fzf` into Powershell, but I'm having trouble understanding what the `-S` or `+S` flag are doing. They can be toggled by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> multiple times. Does anybody have an idea what the difference is?

[image: fzf output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be found in source code of fzf. Specifically [this part](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/87fc1c84b8700e694ec341b36ac3ce29a7a30e6b/src/terminal.go#L1569-L1575):

```
    if t.toggleSort {
        if t.sort {
            output += " +S"
        } else {
            output += " -S"
        }
    }
```

That checks if `--toggle-sort` option is enabled and if the history should be sorted. If it shouldn't, it displays `-S`, otherwise `+S`.

And in PSFzf's source code you can see [here](https://github.com/kelleyma49/PSFzf/blob/b79c3e1e6fbdf0c139549b5c7320faa49c8ace0a/PSFzf.Base.ps1#L794):

```
Invoke-Fzf -Query "$line" -NoSort -Bind ctrl-r:toggle-sort -Scheme history | ForEach-Object { $result = $_ }
```

that it binds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to toggle sorting.

More info about options such as sorting or `--bind` can be found in [fzf man](https://www.mankier.com/1/fzf#--bind). And more details about sorting toggling in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/745).